# Terminal raw mode does not support arrows on Windows

Tags: windows, go, console

I am trying to make my console raw (on Windows), and I'm using ssh/terminal package:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

type sh struct{}

func (sh *sh) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return os.Stdin.Read(b)
}

func (sh *sh) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return os.Stdout.Write(b)
}

func main() {
    oldstate, err := terminal.MakeRaw(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer terminal.Restore(int(os.Stdin.Fd()), oldstate)

    term := terminal.NewTerminal(&sh{}, "")
    term.AutoCompleteCallback = func(line string, pos int, key rune) (newLine string, newPos int, ok bool) {
        fmt.Println("callback:", line, pos, key)

        return "", 0, false
    }

    line, err := term.ReadLine()
    fmt.Println("result:", line, err)
}
```

It works great, and I can catch Ctrl-C and other special keys, but I can't use the arrow keys.

I want the arrow keys to move the cursor or at least invoke `AutoCompleteCallback` where I can move the cursor my self.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Used `github.com/containerd/console` package to make the terminal raw and now it works like a charm.

New code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/containerd/console"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

func main() {
    current := console.Current()
    defer current.Reset()

    if err := current.SetRaw(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    term := terminal.NewTerminal(current, "")
    term.AutoCompleteCallback = func(line string, pos int, key rune) (newLine string, newPos int, ok bool) {
        // fmt.Println("callback:", line, pos, key)

        return "", 0, false
    }

    line, err := term.ReadLine()
    fmt.Println("result:", line, err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed using "github.com/containerd/console" package enabled Arrow/Home/Delete keys on terminal!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps interesting for some people who want to know why `containerd/console` works while `ssh/terminal` does not:

`containerd/console` enables the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT` mode, see [this line in code](https://github.com/containerd/console/blob/65eb8c0396d0cac15c888bcf4d47049c21317b18/console_windows.go#L191) of the currently latest version on Github.

With that, all [control character sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) (cursor movement, coloring, ...) are enabled. Microsoft documents the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT` mode in [High-Level Console Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/high-level-console-modes).